# Jenkins pipeline suddenly started failing while downloading artifacts from artifactory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

My jenkins pipeline which was running without any problem from last two years suddenly started failing while downloading artifacts from jfrog artifactory. Please see the error:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.buildInfo.BuildInfo.publishedDependencies
    in object org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.buildInfo.BuildInfo@39d880ff
    in field org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.declarative.steps.generic.GenericStep$Execution.buildInfo
    in object org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.declarative.steps.generic.DownloadStep$Execution@2a2149fe
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.step
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@7d25da24
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@60f1b3f9
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@60f1b3f9
Caused: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:907)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:857)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:568)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided build log snippet, we are unable to determine the exact cause of the issue. Hence please do validate the Artifactory application logs during the build execution which helps to correlate the events and helps to find the cause.

Also, as the build job is failing while downloading artifacts, in order to rule out the issue with regards to availability of the artifacts at the Artifactory application end, pleaes do validate the existence of the same.

Comment: thanks for your response, which logs i should focus on please , i mean artifactory.log, acces.log, requet.log?

Comment: At first, you can verify the artifactory.log, if there were any access issues then the same will be logged at acces.log.

Comment: Hi Pavan, There are lot of access denied coming. But from today i am seeing this. "accepted download" ones are from my pipeline but other ones are from some other container project from our org:----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: 2022-02-04 11:08:00,564 [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : NA / 10.20.136.160.
2022-02-04 11:08:00,931 [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : gbdbro3 / 10.20.136.160.
2022-02-01 06:08:56,038 [ACCEPTED DOWNLOAD] docker-local:cpopen/iaf-flink-operator-bundle/sha256:3e9fbab4853002b62f4c5b03298286e70c6f1ba510d2c293e8c57a615b10a87d/sha256__26d97873b4d464ef33aaa3900c2d3cd6d8656470c0b5a2fd4e7c16c440591cbb  for client : openshift / 10.20.135.169.
2022-02-01 06:08:57,344 [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : NA / 10.20.135.169.
2022-02-01 06:08:57,346 [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : NA / 10.20.135.169.

Comment: more logs 022-02-04 11:42:44,116 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] jcenter-cache:bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk13/132/bcprov-jdk13-132.pom  for client : NA / 10.20.34.105.
2022-02-04 11:42:44,116 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] jenkins-releases-cache:bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk13/132/bcprov-jdk13-132.pom  for client : NA / 10.20.34.105.
2022-02-04 11:42:44,116 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] maven-org-remote-cache:bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk13/132/bcprov-jdk13-132.pom  for client : NA / 10.20.34.105.
2022-02-04 11:42:44,116 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] maven-oracle-remote-cache:bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk13/132/bcprov-jdk13-132.pom  for client : NA